# Nginx return 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, node.js

Last night I was trying to upload photo on my website and I get error
[image]

I trying to do console.log but they didn`t show anything.After some re-search I notice that disk usage of my server is full so I get AWS EBS  but error is still there

[image]

I try many option and also increase memory on Nginx.

So is there anyone who can tell me what to problem can be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your EBS disk is full. The easiest way to deal with this is to delete files from the disk.

If that's not practical:

- In the AWS console increase the size of your EBS disk ([link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/expand-root-ebs-linux/))
- In Linux extend the size of your file system so it uses the space available on the EBS disk ([link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html))

Comment: Or remove unnecessary files.

Comment: Yep, sorry I thought that was obvious but I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Apparently it's not so obvious as it doesn't seem to have occurred to OP. I have no idea why.

Comment: People have varying levels of experience. I try not to judge, I just provide help.

Comment: It`s fixed. Thank you all !